# How to create Instagram account in python terminal?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have been trying to create a python script that automates Instagram sign up in python but so far I keep getting this error:

```
## Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 327, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 398, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"

[Program finished] ##
```

This is my code:

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as c:
url = 'https://www.instagram.com'
EMAIL = 'wisdomupeh@gmail.com'
PASSWORD = 'testpass1234' 
USERNAME = 'blsdh37fgtest'
NAME = 'Jon Doe'


c.get(url)
csrftoken = c.cookies['csrftoken']

login_data = dict(email=EMAIL, password=PASSWORD, username=USERNAME, fisrt_name=NAME, seamless_login_enabled=1)
c.post(url, data=login_data, headers={"Referer": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/signup/email"}, allow_redirect=True)
page = c.get('https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en#registered')
```

Comment: There is probably some javascript involved with that page that `requests` isn't able to deal with... you might need to use selenium.

Comment: And can you see what the error says?  It did not find a `csrftoken` cookie.  If I do `wget -qSO- https://www.instagram.com`, I don't see that cookie, either.  Perhaps their interface has changed since whatever code you copied this from.